# Hash txt strings in GAS, incorrect line ending

Tags: google-apps-script

I want hash (md5) some txt strings in GAS, and have a problem, may be
incorrect line ending.
Example:

```
test
test
```

correct hash 76ce9f441de2ed5de337d391ad4516b7

using GAS i getting wrong hash: e8230113fbba92427c1c41cf34a80c13

```
function test() {
  var data = 'test\
    test';
  Logger.log(data.MD5());
  return (data.MD5());
}

String.prototype.MD5 = function(charset, toByte) {
  charset = charset || Utilities.Charset.UTF_8;
  var digest = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, this, charset);
  if (toByte) return digest;
  var __ = '';
  for (i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
    var byte = digest[i];
    if (byte < 0) byte += 256;
    var bStr = byte.toString(16);
    if (bStr.length == 1) bStr = '0' + bStr;
    __ += bStr;
  }
  return __;
}
```

Comment: Can provide the source of the correct hash?

Comment: `MD5("test\r\ntest") = "76ce9f441de2ed5de337d391ad4516b7"`

Comment: `MD5("test\ntest") = "be778b473235e210cc577056226536a4"`

Comment: This is my code and it works correct.

Answer (score 0):

As already @Ameen mentioned you are checking different strings

```
function test(){
  var s1 = 'test\ntest';
  var s2 = 'test\r\ntest';

  Logger.log(s1.MD5() === '76ce9f441de2ed5de337d391ad4516b7');
  Logger.log(s2.MD5() === '76ce9f441de2ed5de337d391ad4516b7');
}
```

> ```
> [19-03-22 18:03:11:441 MSK] false
> [19-03-22 18:03:11:442 MSK] true
> ```

A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

It seems you're working under Windows.